# How to fix Swift compile issue trap6

Tags: swift, xcode

The issue happen in Swift3 with XCode10.That maybe be a Swift bug。 Actually，clean and rebuild can solve the issue，but that wast too much time。Any body know a effect way to solve or avoid the issue。Thank you

```
** DESERIALIZATION FAILURE (please include this section in any bug report) ***
could not deserialize type for '_': could not deserialize type for 'operImageView': top-level value not found
Cross-reference to module 'LKImageKit'
... LKImageView

0  swift                    0x000000010460f59a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000010460ed4e SignalHandler(int) + 302
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5e91df5a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fe96482b200 _sigtramp + 99668672
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff5e6bb1ae abort + 127
5  swift                    0x0000000101a74feb swift::ModuleFile::fatal(llvm::Error) + 1915
6  swift                    0x0000000101aac643 getSILDeclRef(swift::ModuleFile*, llvm::ArrayRef<unsigned long long>, unsigned int&) + 307
7  swift                    0x0000000101aae984 swift::SILDeserializer::readVTable(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>) + 740
8  swift                    0x0000000101b5576b swift::SerializedSILLoader::getAllForModule(swift::Identifier, swift::FileUnit*) + 331
9  swift                    0x000000010089d92e performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 34558
10 swift                    0x0000000100891d35 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7717
11 swift                    0x0000000100837965 main + 1349
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff5e60f015 start + 1

WSRecommendHeaderCollectionReusableView~partial.swiftmodule
/Users/levinyang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-hgotlvyrysfhcyeakqaatptobuxm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WSActionSheetRecommendFlowHandler~partial.swiftmodule
---
2.  While deserializing SIL vtable for 'WSNotificationOperCell' in module 'myProject'


** DESERIALIZATION FAILURE (please include this section in any bug report) ***
could not deserialize type for '_': could not deserialize type for 'operImageView': top-level value not found
Cross-reference to module 'LKImageKit'
... LKImageView

0  swift                    0x000000010460f59a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000010460ed4e SignalHandler(int) + 302
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5e91df5a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fe96482b200 _sigtramp + 99668672
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff5e6bb1ae abort + 127
5  swift                    0x0000000101a74feb swift::ModuleFile::fatal(llvm::Error) + 1915
6  swift                    0x0000000101aac643 getSILDeclRef(swift::ModuleFile*, llvm::ArrayRef<unsigned long long>, unsigned int&) + 307
7  swift                    0x0000000101aae984 swift::SILDeserializer::readVTable(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>) + 740
8  swift                    0x0000000101b5576b swift::SerializedSILLoader::getAllForModule(swift::Identifier, swift::FileUnit*) + 331
9  swift                    0x000000010089d92e performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 34558
10 swift                    0x0000000100891d35 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7717
11 swift                    0x0000000100837965 main + 1349
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff5e60f015 start + 1

WSRecommendHeaderCollectionReusableView~partial.swiftmodule
/Users/levinyang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-hgotlvyrysfhcyeakqaatptobuxm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/WSActionSheetRecommendFlowHandler~partial.swiftmodule
---
2.  While deserializing SIL vtable for 'WSNotificationOperCell' in module 'myProject'

error: Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: I got the same error when upgrading to 11.3 from swift 4 to swift 5, run unit test.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Swift compiler bug. It's possible that you're triggering it by linking modules that were compiled by different versions of the compiler, or some other unsupported behavior, but it probably still shouldn't crash.

However, you say it's a Swift 3 problem. The Swift developers no longer support Swift 3. They are working on Swift 5. If you can reproduce the problem in Swift 5, you can file a bug report at https://bugs.swift.org.